# Using saltstack ssh

Tags: ssh, salt-stack

Is there a difference between using salt-proxy ssh and directly salt-ssh? I'm interested because according to documentation both aimed to run remote commands without agent installation on the end machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant simply do salt-ssh on a proxy minion, for which you would have to write your own custom ssh interface to the remote system, because your proxy minion may not support doing salt-ssh.

How to choose between using salt-ssh vs salt-proxy totally depends on the type of a minion system. 
As stated in the saltstack documentation - https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/ssh/index.html and 
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/proxyminion/index.html

For salt-ssh to be used, the remote system must have python installed - one of the criteria. For example, controlling ubuntu from centos.

As stated in the salt-proxy doc,

> Proxy minions are a developing Salt feature that enables controlling
>   devices that, for whatever reason, cannot run a standard salt-minion.
>   Examples include network gear that has an API but runs a proprietary
>   OS, devices with limited CPU or memory, or devices that could run a
>   minion, but for security reasons, will not.